# TextField Value Going to be empty, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using ObservableObject to stored value of textField
Here is my code in ObservableObject

```
    class SignupViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fullname = ""
    @Published var birthday = ""
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var birthDate = Date()
    @Published var isValidEmail = true
    @Published var isEmailAlreadyExist = false
    @Published var isPassword1 = true
    @Published var isPassword2 = true
    @Published var isDisable: Bool = false
}
```

I had created instance like this and used them

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                TextFieldWithoutValidation(text: $signupModel.fullname, placeHolder: "Full name", keyBoardType: .default)
                    .accentColor(Color.black)
                
//                LabelTextField(title: "Full name", text: $signupModel.fullname, keyboardType: .default, contentType: nil)
                
//                TextField("Full name", text: $data.value)
                Text("We’ll use this to issue you a cheque when you make a profit.")
                    .font(.system(size: 11.0))
            }
            DateView(titleText: "Birthday", date: $signupModel.birthDate, labelText: $signupModel.birthday)
            TextFieldWithoutValidation(text: $signupModel.email, placeHolder: "Email", keyBoardType: .emailAddress)
                .accentColor(Color.black)
            if !signupModel.isValidEmail {
                errorView(.emailNotValid)
            }
            SecureTextFieldWithoutValidation(text: $signupModel.password, placeHolder: "Password")
                .accentColor(Color.black)
            if !signupModel.password.isEmpty {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    errorView((signupModel.isPassword1 ? .passwordRight1 : .passwordWrong1))
                    errorView((signupModel.isPassword2 ? .passwordRight2 : .passwordWrong2))
                }
            }
            createButton()
        }
        .padding(.leading, 20) // you can use as per your requirement(-16)
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
        .titleForNavigation("Create your account", displayMode: .large)
        .navigationLayout(AnyView(backButton))
    }
```

But when i am typing something in textField and go to the next textField previous textField text going to be empty automatically

can someone help why it's happening like this

Comment: You should provide more code, of your `View` where the `TextField`s are. It's hard to tell what the issue is otherwise

Comment: I have updated my full code, could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer helps, I was able to replicate your example within a playground.

The object appears to retain its state between renders and after pressing the 'Save' button.

```
import PlaygroundSupport

class SignupViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fullname = ""
    @Published var birthday = ""
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var birthDate = Date()
    @Published var isValidEmail = true
    @Published var isEmailAlreadyExist = false
    @Published var isPassword1 = true
    @Published var isPassword2 = true
    @Published var isDisable: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var signupModel = SignupViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Sign up form")
            TextField("Name", text: $signupModel.fullname)
            TextField("Email", text: $signupModel.email)
            TextField("Password", text: $signupModel.password)
            Button(action: { print("Form data:"); print("\(signupModel.fullname) \(signupModel.email) \(signupModel.password)") }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}

let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Comment: In playground I am not seein the issue you describe, of going between textfields clears the previous textfield. Plus the print proves that the instances contains data. If you run this code in a playground can you see that?

Comment: I had a look at your updated code, but can't replicate your issue as the code is missing your custom views for LabelTextField, DateView, TextFieldWithoutValidation & SecureTextFieldWithoutValidation probably don't need to see errorView.